# Problems with setting up images as background image in SLIDER

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

I've found this really cool image slider plugin(http://www.jqueryscript.net/slideshow/Fullscreen-Responsive-Image-Slideshow-with-jQuery-Phoenix-Slider.html). But I would like to setup the images as background image. I just don't know how to do it.

Can anyone help me?

```js
/**
 * Phoenix is a jQuery Slider that obtains new life by arising from the ashes of its predecessor
 */
(function ($) {

 "use strict";

 // No jQuery? No reborn. 
 if (!$) return;

 var Phoenix = function () {

  var _ = this;

  this.setup = function (element, options) {

   this.element = $(element);
   this.options = options;
   this.interval = null;


   this.ashes = this.element.children("div");
   this.total = this.ashes.length;
   this._static = this.ashes.length == 1;
   this.current = this.ashes.length - 1;

   this.elevation = null;

   this._defaults = {
    delay: 10000,
    speed: 400,
    height: null,
    fullscreen: true,
    dots: true,
    keys: true,
    complete: function (index, currentElement, prevElement) {}
   };

   this.init();
  };

  this.init = function () {

      // Store a reference to the original remove method.
      var originalMethod = jQuery.fn.transition || jQuery.fn.animate;

      // Define overriding method.
      jQuery.fn.spitFire = function(){
          // Execute the original method.
          return originalMethod.apply( this, arguments );
      }

   this._defaults = $.extend(this._defaults, this.options);

   var ash, pic;

   $(window).on('resize', function () {
    _.resize();
   }).trigger('resize');

   // Show Dots
   this._defaults.dots && !_._static && this.dots();

   //  Custom keyboard support
   this._defaults.keys && !_._static && $(document).keydown(this.keys);

   this.ashes.each(function (index) {

    ash = $(this);

    pic = ash.children("img");

    ash.css({
     'background-image': 'url(' + pic.attr('src') + ')',
     // 'filter': "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='" + pic.attr('src') + "', sizingMethod='scale')",
     // '-ms-filter': "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='" + pic.attr('src') + "', sizingMethod='scale')",
    });

    if (index == 0) ash.css('z-index', 4);

    pic.remove();
   });

   // Adding Touch Support with jQueryMobile
   !_._static && $().swiperight && $().swipeleft && _.element.swipeleft(_.next) && _.element.swiperight(_.prev);

   this.next();
   !_._static && this.play();
  };

  this.resize = function () {

   this.computeTallness();

   this.element.css({
    'height': (this._defaults.fullscreen === true ? $(window).height() : _.elevation) + 'px'
   });
  };

  this.computeTallness = function() {
   if (this._defaults.fullscreen === true) {

    _.elevation = $(window).height();

   } else {
    if ((typeof _._defaults.height).toLowerCase() === 'string') {
     if (_._defaults.height.slice(-1) === '%') {
      _.elevation = $(window).height() * (_._defaults.height.substr(0, _._defaults.height.length - 1) / 100);
     } 
    } else if ((typeof _._defaults.height).toLowerCase() === 'number') {
     _.elevation = _._defaults.height;
    } else {
     _.elevation = _.element.height() == 0 ? $(window).height() : _.element.height();
    }
   }
  };

  this.dots = function () {
   //  Create the HTML
   var html = '<div class="container-dots-wrapper"><div class="container-dots-inner"><ol class="dots">';
   $.each(this.ashes, function (index) {
    html += '<li class="dot' + (index < 1 ? ' active' : '') + '">' + (index + 1) + '</li>';
   });
   html += '</ol></div></div>';

   //  Add it to the Slider
   this.element.append(html).find('.dot').click(function () {
    _.move($(this).index(), true);
   });
  }

  this.index = function () {
   return _.current;
  }

  this.destroy = function () {

   // Remove elements, unregister listeners, etc
   // TODO

   // Remove data
   this.element.removeData();
  };

  this.play = function () {
   _.interval = setInterval(function () {
    _.next();
   }, _._defaults.delay);

   return _;
  };

  //  Stop autoplay
  this.stop = function () {
   _.interval = clearInterval(_.interval);

   return _;
  };

  //  Keypresses
  this.keys = function (e) {
   var key = e.which;
   var map = {
    //  Prev/next
    37: _.prev,
    39: _.next,
   };

   if ($.isFunction(map[key])) {
    map[key](true);
   }
  };

  //  Arrow navigation
  this.next = function (f) {
   return _.move(_.current + 1, f);
  };

  this.prev = function (f) {
   return _.move(_.current - 1, f);
  };

  this.move = function (index, f) {

   if (index == _.current) return;

   var newIndex, oldIndex,
    oldIndex = _.current,
    oldElement = this.ashes.eq(_.current),
    newElement;

   //  If it's out of bounds, go to the first slide
   if (!this.ashes.eq(index).length) index = 0;
   if (index < 0) index = (this.ashes.length - 1);

   _.current = index;

   newIndex = _.current;
   newElement = this.ashes.eq(newIndex);

   newElement.css('opacity', 1);

   if (_._static) return;

   _.element.find('.dot:eq(' + index + ')').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');

   oldElement.spitFire({
    'opacity': 0,
    'duration': this._defaults.speed
   }, function () {
    oldElement.css('z-index', 'auto');
    newElement.css('z-index', 4);

    if (f) _.stop().play();

    if (typeof (_._defaults.complete) === 'function') _._defaults.complete(newIndex, newElement, oldElement);
   });
  }

  this.getRandomInt = function (min, max) {
   return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
  }

 };


 //  Create a jQuery plugin
 return $.fn.phoenix = function (o) {
  var len = this.length;

  //  Enable multiple-slider support
  return $(this.each(function (index) {
   //  Cache a copy of $(this), so it 
   var me = $(this),
    instance = (new Phoenix).setup(me, o);

   //  Invoke a Phoenix Slider instance
   me.data('phoenix' + (len > 1 ? '-' + (index + 1) : ''), instance);
  })).data('phoenix');
 };

})(jQuery);
```

```css
.phoenix-slider {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 630px;
  position: relative;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.phoenix-slider .phoenix-feather {
  background: transparent none scroll no-repeat center top;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
  opacity: 0;
}

.phoenix-slider .reborn { z-index: 4; }

.phoenix-slider .phoenix-feather > img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: none;
}

.container-dots-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 10px;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 9;
}

.container-dots-inner {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
}

.dots {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.dots li {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  margin: 0 4px 7px 4px;
  text-indent: -999em;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: .5;
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.5));
  -moz-filter: drop-shadow(0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.5));
  -ms-filter: drop-shadow(0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.5));
  -o-filter: drop-shadow(0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.5));
  filter: drop-shadow(0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.5));
}

.dots li.active {
  width: 11px;
  height: 11px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  left: 8px;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="phoenix-slider">

  <div class="phoenix-feather">
    <img src="img/1.jpg" alt="" />
  </div>

  <div class="phoenix-feather">
    <img src="img/2.jpg" alt="" />
  </div>

  <div class="phoenix-feather">
    <img src="img/3.jpg" alt="" />
  </div>

  <div class="phoenix-feather">
    <img src="img/4.jpg" alt="" />
  </div>

  <div class="phoenix-feather">
    <img src="img/5.jpg" alt="" />
  </div>

  <div class="phoenix-feather">
    <img src="img/6.jpg" alt="" />
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: please Check it my demo

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

First You can Add in this file in your jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.phoenix-slider').phoenix({
        fullscreen: true,
        height: '85%'
    });

});
```

```js
   

/**
 * Phoenix is a jQuery Slider that obtains new life by arising from the ashes of its predecessor
 */
(function ($) {

 "use strict";

 // No jQuery? No reborn. 
 if (!$) return;

 var Phoenix = function () {

  var _ = this;

  this.setup = function (element, options) {

   this.element = $(element);
   this.options = options;
   this.interval = null;


   this.ashes = this.element.children("div");
   this.total = this.ashes.length;
   this._static = this.ashes.length == 1;
   this.current = this.ashes.length - 1;

   this.elevation = null;

   this._defaults = {
    delay: 10000,
    speed: 400,
    height: null,
    fullscreen: true,
    dots: true,
    keys: true,
    complete: function (index, currentElement, prevElement) {}
   };

   this.init();
  };

  this.init = function () {

      // Store a reference to the original remove method.
      var originalMethod = jQuery.fn.transition || jQuery.fn.animate;

      // Define overriding method.
      jQuery.fn.spitFire = function(){
          // Execute the original method.
          return originalMethod.apply( this, arguments );
      }

   this._defaults = $.extend(this._defaults, this.options);

   var ash, pic;

   $(window).on('resize', function () {
    _.resize();
   }).trigger('resize');

   // Show Dots
   this._defaults.dots && !_._static && this.dots();

   //  Custom keyboard support
   this._defaults.keys && !_._static && $(document).keydown(this.keys);

   this.ashes.each(function (index) {

    ash = $(this);

    pic = ash.children("img");

    ash.css({
     'background-image': 'url(' + pic.attr('src') + ')',
     // 'filter': "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='" + pic.attr('src') + "', sizingMethod='scale')",
     // '-ms-filter': "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='" + pic.attr('src') + "', sizingMethod='scale')",
    });

    if (index == 0) ash.css('z-index', 4);

    pic.remove();
   });

   // Adding Touch Support with jQueryMobile
   !_._static && $().swiperight && $().swipeleft && _.element.swipeleft(_.next) && _.element.swiperight(_.prev);

   this.next();
   !_._static && this.play();
  };

  this.resize = function () {

   this.computeTallness();

   this.element.css({
    'height': (this._defaults.fullscreen === true ? $(window).height() : _.elevation) + 'px'
   });
  };

  this.computeTallness = function() {
   if (this._defaults.fullscreen === true) {

    _.elevation = $(window).height();

   } else {
    if ((typeof _._defaults.height).toLowerCase() === 'string') {
     if (_._defaults.height.slice(-1) === '%') {
      _.elevation = $(window).height() * (_._defaults.height.substr(0, _._defaults.height.length - 1) / 100);
     } 
    } else if ((typeof _._defaults.height).toLowerCase() === 'number') {
     _.elevation = _._defaults.height;
    } else {
     _.elevation = _.element.height() == 0 ? $(window).height() : _.element.height();
    }
   }
  };

  this.dots = function () {
   //  Create the HTML
   var html = '<div class="container-dots-wrapper"><div class="container-dots-inner"><ol class="dots">';
   $.each(this.ashes, function (index) {
    html += '<li class="dot' + (index < 1 ? ' active' : '') + '">' + (index + 1) + '</li>';
   });
   html += '</ol></div></div>';

   //  Add it to the Slider
   this.element.append(html).find('.dot').click(function () {
    _.move($(this).index(), true);
   });
  }

  this.index = function () {
   return _.current;
  }

  this.destroy = function () {

   // Remove elements, unregister listeners, etc
   // TODO

   // Remove data
   this.element.removeData();
  };

  this.play = function () {
   _.interval = setInterval(function () {
    _.next();
   }, _._defaults.delay);

   return _;
  };

  //  Stop autoplay
  this.stop = function () {
   _.interval = clearInterval(_.interval);

   return _;
  };

  //  Keypresses
  this.keys = function (e) {
   var key = e.which;
   var map = {
    //  Prev/next
    37: _.prev,
    39: _.next,
   };

   if ($.isFunction(map[key])) {
    map[key](true);
   }
  };

  //  Arrow navigation
  this.next = function (f) {
   return _.move(_.current + 1, f);
  };

  this.prev = function (f) {
   return _.move(_.current - 1, f);
  };

  this.move = function (index, f) {

   if (index == _.current) return;

   var newIndex, oldIndex,
    oldIndex = _.current,
    oldElement = this.ashes.eq(_.current),
    newElement;

   //  If it's out of bounds, go to the first slide
   if (!this.ashes.eq(index).length) index = 0;
   if (index < 0) index = (this.ashes.length - 1);

   _.current = index;

   newIndex = _.current;
   newElement = this.ashes.eq(newIndex);

   newElement.css('opacity', 1);

   if (_._static) return;

   _.element.find('.dot:eq(' + index + ')').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');

   oldElement.spitFire({
    'opacity': 0,
    'duration': this._defaults.speed
   }, function () {
    oldElement.css('z-index', 'auto');
    newElement.css('z-index', 4);

    if (f) _.stop().play();

    if (typeof (_._defaults.complete) === 'function') _._defaults.complete(newIndex, newElement, oldElement);
   });
  }

  this.getRandomInt = function (min, max) {
   return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
  }

 };


 //  Create a jQuery plugin
 return $.fn.phoenix = function (o) {
  var len = this.length;

  //  Enable multiple-slider support
  return $(this.each(function (index) {
   //  Cache a copy of $(this), so it 
   var me = $(this),
    instance = (new Phoenix).setup(me, o);

   //  Invoke a Phoenix Slider instance
   me.data('phoenix' + (len > 1 ? '-' + (index + 1) : ''), instance);
  })).data('phoenix');
 };

})(jQuery);
```

```css
.phoenix-slider {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 630px;
  position: relative;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.phoenix-slider .phoenix-feather {
  background: transparent none scroll no-repeat center top;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
  opacity: 0;
}

.phoenix-slider .reborn { z-index: 4; }

.phoenix-slider .phoenix-feather > img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: none;
}

.container-dots-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 10px;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 9;
}

.container-dots-inner {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
}

.dots {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.dots li {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  margin: 0 4px 7px 4px;
  text-indent: -999em;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: .5;
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.5));
  -moz-filter: drop-shadow(0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.5));
  -ms-filter: drop-shadow(0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.5));
  -o-filter: drop-shadow(0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.5));
  filter: drop-shadow(0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.5));
}

.dots li.active {
  width: 11px;
  height: 11px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  left: 8px;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/3.0.1/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<div class="phoenix-slider">
  <div class="phoenix-feather">
   <img src="http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Fullscreen-Responsive-Image-Slideshow-with-jQuery-Phoenix-Slider/img/1.jpg" alt="" />
  </div>
  <!-- END ash -->

  <div class="phoenix-feather">
   <img src="http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Fullscreen-Responsive-Image-Slideshow-with-jQuery-Phoenix-Slider/img/2.jpg" alt="" />
  </div>
  <!-- END ash -->

  <div class="phoenix-feather">
   <img src="http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Fullscreen-Responsive-Image-Slideshow-with-jQuery-Phoenix-Slider/img/3.jpg" alt="" />
  </div>
  <!-- END ash -->

  <div class="phoenix-feather">
   <img src="http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Fullscreen-Responsive-Image-Slideshow-with-jQuery-Phoenix-Slider/img/4.jpg" alt="" />
  </div>
  <!-- END ash -->

  <div class="phoenix-feather">
   <img src="http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Fullscreen-Responsive-Image-Slideshow-with-jQuery-Phoenix-Slider/img/5.jpg" alt="" />
  </div>
  <!-- END ash -->

  <div class="phoenix-feather">
   <img src="http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Fullscreen-Responsive-Image-Slideshow-with-jQuery-Phoenix-Slider/img/6.jpg" alt="" />
  </div>
  <!-- END ash -->
 </div>
 <!-- END phoenix-slider -->  

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```